# can we publish user app rating from my ionic app to Play Store/App Store without redirecting user to Play Store?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play

can we publish user given app rating from ionic app to Play Store/App Store without redirecting the user to Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

I see your question is tagged as `android` but then you also ask for App Store in the question. So, in case you'd need this for iOS here's my answer:

Since iOS `10.3` you can make use of the awesome InAppReview from Apple. I can attest to the fact that this new way of reviewing apps has been very fruitful for our apps in terms of the number of reviews. You can read an even more compelling case study here of how [Instagram doubled their reviews](https://medium.com/huggingface/instagram-doubled-its-ios-reviews-in-a-week-thanks-to-this-new-in-app-review-popup-52333d4f4ce6).

The cordova plugin, which is very easy to use and implement is here: https://github.com/omaxlive/com.omarben.inappreview.

For brevity, and in case that StackOverflow seize to exist (unlikely), here are the steps to use it:

Install the plugin: `cordova plugins add com.omarben.inappreview`

Call it in the code like this:

```
var requestReview = function(){
    try{
        var success = function() {
            console.log("Success");
        }
        var failure = function() {
            console.log("Error calling plugin");
        }

        inappreview.requestReview(success, failure);
    }catch(e){
        console.log("catch: "+e);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

No, the rating can only be done in the playstore. Otherwise it would be a lot harder to prevent fake ratings and reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Launch Review plugin of ionic please follow link
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/launch-review

install plugin by following by these:-

```
 ionic cordova plugin add cordova-launch-review 
 npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/launch-review
```

then import this in your app.module.ts file by:-

```
import { LaunchReview } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/launch-review/ngx';
```

then use this code where you want to show rating reviews of play store and run run this code when platform is ready.

```
if(this.launchReview.isRatingSupported()){
  this.launchReview.rating()
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully launched rating dialog'));
}
```

it is working I have used it but it will not show rating popup multiple times in a short period of time because of play store policy.

Comment: amit kumar, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @mozway have you used  this plugin?

Comment: no, I'm just commenting from an agnostic point of view. I don't have a personal interest in the question myself, just on the quality of the Q/A

Answer (score -1):

Not possible .

Google only allows transfer within Playstore i.e transferring App to the different developer account.